# Accept all types as argument in function

Tags: c++, arguments

How can I in C++ make a function accept every Object, so I can give it numbers, String or other Objects. I am not very well in C++, I hope it's not a totally stupid question...

Edit: Ok, an example: if you want to try to wrap the std::cout streams into normal functions, that funtion should be able to accept everything - from Integers over Floats to complex Objects. I hope it's more clear now!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: And the answer probably involves templates...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can **overload** your function for different types, i.e.

```
size_t func(int);
size_t func(std::string);
```

Alternatively and/or additionally, you can provide a function **template**, which is a way to tell the compiler how to generate your function for any particular type, for example

```
template<typename T>
size_t func(T const&) { return sizeof(T); }
```

You may use more advanced techniques such as SFINAE to effectively overload those template functions, i.e. to use different templates for different kind of types `T` (i.e. integral types, pointer, built-in types, pod, etc). The compiler will then pick the best-fitting `func()` (if any) for any function call it encounters and, if this is a template, generate an appropriate function.
This requires no re-coding.

A completely different approach is to use a generic **erasure type**, such as `boost::any`, when the function will need to resolve the expected types at coding-time (as opposed to compile-time):

```
size_t func(boost::any const&x)
{
  auto i = boost::any_cast<const int*>(x);
  if(i) return func(*i);
  // etc for other types, but this must be done at coding time!
}
```

Comment: Since C++20, it's also possible to [infer parameter types using `auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template).

Comment: "coding-time"!? You mean "run-time", right?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I actually meant coding time. The point is that while the program resolves the type at run-time, the code dealing with possible types must be coded for each possible time, which happens at coding time.

Answer (score 10):

You can use templates for this purpose:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T const & value)
{
    // value is of some type T, which can be any type at all.
}
```

What you can actually do with the value *may* be rather limited without knowing its type -- it depends on the goal of your function.  (If someone attempts to call the function with an argument type that causes that function specialization to be ill-formed then your template function will *fail to instantiate* and it will be a compile-time error.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can pass a void pointer as a parameter.

```
void foo(void* bar);
```

Comment: Using `void *` is rarely the answer in modern C++.

Comment: I agree. I probably should have provided a template example as others have stated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you might wanna try using templates http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for **templates**.
I suggest you read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part).